# How to change file permissions with Cpanel or Filezilla for MantisBT or any file / folder?

Tags: php, permissions, cpanel

I would like to install Mantisbt on a shared hosting account. I'm not a developer or network engineer myself but I found easy to follow instructions here: https://www.tmdhosting.com/kb/answer/re-mantisbt-hosting-requirements-mantisbt-manual-installation/

I downloaded the zip file from mantisbt.org, uploaded it to the public_html folder, and extracted the file there. I also created a MySQL database.

When I now go to mydomain.com/mantis (which is the folder name in which I extracted the files) I get a 500 Internal Server Error. Under "Errors" in cPanel I find the following:

> SoftException in Application.cpp:267: File
>   “/home/username/public_html/mantis/index.php” is writeable by group

I think this means there is a permission problem. But I have no idea how I can solve that... Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I'm not an engineer myself but am able to do basic stuff in cPanel.

Comment: Hi, cPanel questions are off-topic for serverfault, but you should try to change user permissions for that directory so that the user group can't write to it, e.g. something like `chmod -R 750 /home/username/public_html/mantis/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 10 64-bit

How to solve error messages:

```
500 Internal Server Error
SoftException in Application.cpp:267: File “/home/username/public_html/mantis/index.php” is writeable by group
```

How to change file / folder permissions with Cpanel or Filezilla for MantisBT or any file / folder. Your `paths` might be different.

Remove write access for `Group` for directory `mantis` using FileZilla. Do not recurse. It will take ~60 seconds.

[image: screenshot filezilla]

How to change file / directory permissions with [Cpanel](https://www.bing.com/search?&q=how+to+use+the+cpanel+file+manager) or [Putty](https://www.bing.com/search?q=how%20to%20install%20and%20use%20putty%20on%20windows). For a simple job (one file or directory) I would use the Cpanel File Manager but learn how to use a command line SSH and Telnet client like Putty.

From least to most; remove write access for `Group` for `see list below`, wait a few seconds, open `index.php`:

1. `index.php`. Do not recurse.
2. directory `mantis`. Do not recurse.
3. directory `mantis`. Recurse - Apply to directories only.
4. directory `mantis`. Recurse into subdirectories and apply to all files and directories.

Directory should be `755`. File should be `644`. [755](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/uchmod.htm) means: "Directory permissions are set to: User can read, write, and execute; group members and other users can read and execute, but cannot write."

1. Open the Cpanel File Manager:

[image: screenhost cpanel file manager]

2. Navigate to the `mantis` directory: `/home/username/public_html/mantis`. Your `paths` might be different. For me it would be in the `htdocs` directory.

[image: Cpanel]

3. Left click `mantis`, right click `index.php` and click `CHMOD`

[image: chmod]

4. Remove the check mark from `group write`

[image: what you have. what you want.]

Click `OK`, give the server a few seconds to change the permissions and open `index.php`. If it does not solve your problem progress through the logic of "one, the other, both, or everything." If it is everything and there are a lot of files learn how to use a SSH and Telnet client like [Putty](https://www.bing.com/search?q=how%20to%20install%20and%20use%20putty%20on%20windows). See commands below.

Reference: **Use the correct path**. Change `cd` and `mantis`.

[cpp267-file-home-public_html-index-php-is-writeable-by-group](https://www.basezap.com/solved-softexception-in-application-cpp267-file-home-public_html-index-php-is-writeable-by-group/)

```
cd /home/username/public_html/
find mantis -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find mantis -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

[error-500-file-is-writeable-by-group-no-whmcpanel-softexception](https://www.translatetheweb.com/?from=pt&to=en&ref=SERP&refd=www.bing.com&dl=en&rr=UC&a=https%3A%2F%2Fblog.masterdaweb.com%2Fartigos%2Ferror-500-file-is-writeable-by-group-no-whmcpanel-softexception%2F):

> Learn how to use [CHMOD](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/uchmod.htm). Using a SSH and Telnet client like [Putty](https://www.bing.com/search?q=how%20to%20install%20and%20use%20putty%20on%20windows) access the cPanel account by SSH, navigate to the directory corresponding to the problem, and run [the following commands](https://winaero.com/blog/run-chmod-separately-for-files-and-directories/) to change file permissions to 644, and directories to 755:

```
#change directory / subdirectory and files to 644
chmod -R 644 /home/username/public_html/mantis/
#change directory / subdirectory to 755
find /home/username/public_html/mantis/ -type d -print0 |xargs -0 chmod 755
```

See https://www.puttygen.com/putty-commands

[experts-exchange.com](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/29074641/Migration-and-permissions.html)

> Error log says  SoftException in Application.cpp:267: File
>   "/home/.../public_html/index.php" is writeable by group. a 500 error
>   is served. Changing to 644 displays the page properly.

Comments:

> Thanks, I was able to solve the issue by removing write access to all
>   files and directories for the `mantis` directory. Changing it for
>   some of the directories / files proved not enough. I used FileZilla to
>   do this. It was quite easy. – Marty

How to solve error messages:

500 Internal Server Error
SoftException in Application.cpp:267: File “/home/username/public_html/mantis/index.php” is writeable by group

Comment: Thanks, I was able to solve the issue by removing write access to all files and folders for the mantis folder (just changing it for some of the folders/files proofed not enough). Used FileZilla to do this, since I am somewhat familiar with. Was quite easy to do that there.

Comment: @mar check the graphic I added to my answer and tell me if I got it right. I do not see the need to remove write permissions for the owner to solve your error message. Did you try to change `index.php` first and it did not work? Does `mantis` have sub-directories? Once you clicked `OK` in Filezilla how many seconds did it take to make the changes?

Comment: @mar Would you change the title of the question to: How to change file permissions with Cpanel or Filezilla for MantisBT or any file / folder?

Comment: Yes, the images are correct. I tried `index.php` first then got the error for another file and folder. `mantis` indeed has subdirectories. It took FileZilla over a minute to change all file permissions.

Comment: @mar Was the second folder a sub-folder of mantis or on the same level as mantis?

Comment: A sub-folder of mantis